# Inputs was not working by dynamic component

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I implemented with ndc-dynamic for creating dynamic component.

It works very well with outputs, but inputs was not working.

I will show my code.

```
 <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="item.widgetComponent; ndcDynamicInputs: inputs; ndcDynamicOutputs: outputs">
```

in the ts file

```
 aButtonDisabled: boolean;
  bButtonDisabled: boolean;
  inputs = {
    disabledAView: this.aButtonDisabled,
    disabledBView: this.bButtonDisabled
  };
```

this two codes are in parent component.

the child component:

```
 @Input() disabledVehicleAView: boolean;
  @Input() disabledVehicleBView: boolean:
```

and in the HTML

```
  <mat-grid-tile>
        <button [disabled]="disabledVehicleBView">
       </button>
      </mat-grid-tile>
      <mat-grid-tile>
        <button  [disabled]="disabledVehicleAView">
          </button>
      </mat-grid-tile>
```

Did I do something wrong?

any solutions?

Best Regards,

Leo

Comment: Can you create repro on stackblitz.com? I guess you need to manually call change detection after setting input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the value of `inputs` whenever the value of `this.aButtonDisabled` or `this.bButtonDisabled` is changing.

**Your main static component - HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="aButtonDisabled" (ngModelChange)="onAButtonChange($event)"/>aButtonDisabled 
<input type="checkbox" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="bButtonDisabled" (ngModelChange)="onBButtonChange($event)"/>bButtonDisabled

<ng-container 
               *ngComponentOutlet="component; 
               ndcDynamicInputs: inputs; 
               ndcDynamicOutputs: outputs"></ng-container>
```

**Your main static component - TS**

```
onAButtonChange() {
    console.log(this.aButtonDisabled)
    this.inputs = {
      ...this.inputs,
      ...{ disabledVehicleAView: this.aButtonDisabled }
    }
  }

  onBButtonChange() {
    console.log(this.bButtonDisabled)
    this.inputs = {
      ...this.inputs,
      ...{ disabledVehicleBView: this.bButtonDisabled }
    }
  }
```

`onAButtonChange` or `onAButtonChange` methods can be called when User change the value from a control, for example a checkbox's `onChange` event. In your case it may not be a checkbox, but some how you may be chaning the value of `this.aButtonDisabled` that time call the `onAButtonChange()` method also

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component-cqtu97?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it was not working.

Comment: can you add a working sample ? hope you have the closing of `</ng-container>`. Its working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component-cqtu97?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: yes, this example I have also found, and I have exactly implemented such as this example.

Comment: I have tried, if I changed the code with  aButtonDisabled: boolean;
  bButtonDisabled: boolean;
  inputs = {
    disabledAView: true,
    disabledBView: ture
  }; It works

Comment: I think that the inputs can not listen the changes from variables

Comment: when are you calling my method `onAButtonChange()` ?

Comment: can you give me a complett example?

Comment: Thank you very much...I will try your solution in my application

Comment: @SreekumarP I have a question, I'm currently using ng-dynamic-component to use differents type of widgets on a dashboard, my question is the following: if I modify the Input data in a child (widget) the changes will be reflected in the parent (dashboard) ? If no, how can I handle this ?

Comment: @Jessy: you need to use `Output` for communicating from a child to parent. Take a look at outputs variable in appcomponent and how its used => I have updated the working demo with output also https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-ng-dynamic-component-ncq9fm?file=app/hello.component.ts